# Powerful Debian/Ubuntu Laptop without intrusive hardware

Tags: laptop, linux

I am looking for a laptop that can run debian/ubuntu out of the box without going nuts over wifi drivers and I could use your suggestions. I need:

- Modern intel processor
- 16GB - 32GB Ram
- 256GB+ SSD
- Acceptable battery life
- Does not overheat

But I am concerned with privacy. The computer must *not have*:

- Bluetooth
- Camera
- Microphone
- Biometrics

Other nice things I don't need:

- No full hd screen or pixel-dense-screen. I can't see that many pixels anyway.
- No touch screen
- Not 2-in-1 screen

In plain words, I want an old-fashioned laptop equipped with a modern processor and ssd harddrive that is debian/ubuntu verified, without all the intrusive hardware that inevitably comes with modern laptops and seems impossible to get rid of.

I wonder if any company creates laptops with this flavor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is *"Acceptable battery life"* for you? Are you willing to void your warranty in order to remove unwanted components (mic, webcam, bluetooth card) ? What screen size do you want? (A 17.3" screen is *almost always* 1080p, 15.6" is also often 1080p..., how dense is *too* dense?)

Comment: Hi Romen! Battery life? 6 hours? I'd rather these components were not included in the first place. I thought there would be a laptop brand offering laptops like these but there are none. However there is a market for refurbished old laptops like the one I require. I'd like a 14' screen if possible. A desktop resolution of 1920x is good enough, I don't require more. And 72pix/inch is good too.

Comment: Hi flaab! *"I'd like a 14' screen if possible. A desktop resolution of 1920x is good enough, I don't require more. And 72pix/inch is good too. "* -- screen resolution, size, and PPI are all related. a 14" 1920x1080 screen will be ~157 PPI. A 14" screen at ~72 PPI would have a resolution of 880x495. I'm not sure that combination even exists... What is the max PPI that you find acceptable?

Comment: Thanks! I just don't want a retina display or a huge pixel density. Any regular screen will do.